# Copied page designer file reverting to original class name

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I needed to make a new page which was very similar to another so I simply copied it and renamed both the file and the class name within the code.

So far so good.

However, if I make a change to the markup, the designer file in the new page forgets the new class name and reverts to the old one causing compile errors.

It is easy enough to fix but is there some way of making the change stick rather than having to do this each time?

Also, should I have cloned the page a different way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I thought this was just a feature but when I ran the new page it routed to the old one.

On inspection, the problem was this line:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Codebehind="WibbleNew.aspx.vb" Inherits="Wibble"%>
```

I had changed the **Codebehind** section but not the **Inherits**, so it should have been:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Codebehind="WibbleNew.aspx.vb" Inherits="WibbleNew"%>
```

I did say it had been a while... :-/

Answer (score 1):

You could put the common features in a master page and then just create separate pages for the two sets of differences.

There is a good intro to that here: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_masterpages.asp

Comment: I don't doubt this is a good idea but I want to keep the existing page as a reference as I'm not overly familiar with the legacy code and also haven't touched ASP.NET in something like 10 years.